# How do I know which image view to update after selecting a photo?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I have a view with 2 UIImageViews and 2 buttons in order to select 2 different pictures with UIImagePickerViewController. It actually works but when I upload 1 image the other UIView Image is also selecting the same image.

What am I doing wrong ?

```
}

@IBAction func uploadButton(_ sender: Any) {

    let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
    imagePickerController.delegate = self

    let actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: "Photo Source", message: "Choose a source", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

    actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: .default, handler: { (action:UIAlertAction) in

        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera) {
            imagePickerController.sourceType = .camera
            self.present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }else{
            print("Camera not available")
        }


    }))

    actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Photo Library", style: .default, handler: { (action:UIAlertAction) in
        imagePickerController.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        self.present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }))

    actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))

    self.present(actionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)


}

@IBAction func coverButton(_ sender: Any) {

    let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
    imagePickerController.delegate = self

    let actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: "Photo Source", message: "Choose a source", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

    actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: .default, handler: { (action:UIAlertAction) in

        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera) {
            imagePickerController.sourceType = .camera
            self.present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }else{
            print("Camera not available")
        }


    }))

    actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Photo Library", style: .default, handler: { (action:UIAlertAction) in
        imagePickerController.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        self.present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }))

    actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))

    self.present(actionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)




}
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage

    profileImage.image = image
    backgroundImage.image = image

    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

}

func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

Comment: You always set image to both views in imagePickerController  didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo method.

Comment: What do i should replace instead and thanks for answering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have duplicate code and no way to determine which image view to update after a picture is selected/taken. You need to refactor your code.

Add a property to your class:

```
var chosenImageView: UIImageView?
```

Then put your common code into its own method:

```
function selectPhoto() {
    let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
    imagePickerController.delegate = self

    let actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: "Photo Source", message: "Choose a source", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera) {
        actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: .default, handler: { (action:UIAlertAction) in
            imagePickerController.sourceType = .camera
            self.present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }))
    }else{
        print("Camera not available")
    }

    actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Photo Library", style: .default, handler: { (action:UIAlertAction) in
        imagePickerController.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        self.present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }))

    actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))

    self.present(actionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Note how the Camera button isn't shown if there is no camera.

Then refactor your two actions:

```
@IBAction func uploadButton(_ sender: Any) {
    chosenImageView = profileImage

    selectPhoto()
}

@IBAction func coverButton(_ sender: Any) {
    chosenImageView = backgroundImage

    selectPhoto()
}
```

And lastly the delegate methods:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage

    chosenImageView?.image = image

    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```